# Advantages of using Appium vs Uiautomator

Tags: android, automation, appium, ui-automation

I'm new to mobile automation and I'm planning to automate a native Android app (not my own so I have only the APK file) so I was reading about the tools available for Android automation. I came across Appium which I understand uses Uiautomator to do so. 
I was wondering what are the advantages of using Appium instead of directly using Uiautomator or in which case is better to use Appium or Uiautomator.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use native tools for mobile automation then you have to **learn different languages** to write scripts; e.g. a `UIAutomator` script will have to be written in Coffee.  Similarly for iOS `XCUITest`, you have to know Swift C or direct methods of the `XCUIElement` class.

But if you use `Appium`, you can write scripts in your favorite language; e.g.: Java,C#, Python, Ruby, JavaScript, etc.

With Appium you can use a single framework for both android and iOS platforms. If you use native tools, then you have to maintain different frameworks for you AUT.

**Summary** -

1. **Native tools** - Language dependency, different platforms requiring different frameworks to be maintained, script execution is faster.
2. **Appium** - No/Minimal language dependency, easy-to-maintain frameworks, script execution is slower as it is a wrapper over native SDKs.

Answer (score 3):

**UIAutomator** is only specific to android devices, similarly for iOS devices there was **XCUITEST\UIAUTOMATION**

With this approach (UI Automator) you will need to have two frameworks in case you have same app for testing on IOS and Android OS (which is usually the case).

Hence Appium arrives as a wrapper which can be used for both android\iOS mobile OS.

If you are a beginner, you can refer below tutorial to learn mobile automation

https://automationlab0000.wordpress.com/2018/09/10/appium/